# How to enable wol by default for new connections with network manager?

Tags: network-manager

How can I enable WOL (magic) by default for every new ethernet conncetion by default with the network manager (ubuntu mate 18.04).
(background: I'm using an cloning software to use one image on multiple computers)

Comment: WoL is typically something you enable at the *system firmware* level, for ethernet adapters, rather than as part of the OS with Network Manager...

Comment: Buth there is the option „nmcli connection modify Kabelgebundene\ Verbindung\ 2 802-3-ethernet.wake-on-lan magic“ and it works but I need to make this as default for every new connection, not only for „Kabelgebundene\ Verbindung\ 2“

Comment: [This](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/networkmanager-list/2015-September/msg00018.html) suggests there is a global setting which you can add to  `NetworkManager.conf` (`ethernet.wake-on-lan`) - which is applied if the setting is not set per connection. And that seems to be confirmed in the [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Wake-on-LAN#NetworkManager) - you probably want ti set it to `magic` though, and not `disabled`. That sounds like it's what you're after.